# How to know what site opened in Firefox loads CPU on 90%

Tags: performance, firefox, cpu-usage

Some sites opened in Firefox take 90% of CPU usage.
Is there some diagnostic utility or plugin to know what these sites are?
If site is known, is it possible to know what script, plugin or something else is reason of 90% CPU usage?

Comment: How do you know they took 90% but don't know what the sites were? You really need to narrow this down so that you can recreate the issues with proper diagnostics on (and ideally in Chrome with its superior dev tools). I can help if you update your question.

Answer (score 0):

There are also many other issues that can cause high CPU usage outside of Firefox itself. I usually find this type of problem has to do with available memory. If you don't have much available memory left, then the CPU usage is caused by the OS thrashing (i.e. moving pages between virtual and real memory). What I do is to kill Firefox / Chrome with the task manager, and then have Firefox / Chrome restore the pages. Then I clean up the number of tabs I have open. Another thing that can cause CPU/memory usage issues are badly designed plug-ins. Disable them and see if you still have an problem.